# Unable to read file by perl File::Tail

Tags: html, linux, perl, cgi

i am trying to get realtime tail of a nginx log file using perl CGI.
i have given permission to file is 644.
my perl cgi code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use File::Tail;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

$| = 1; #set auto flush on

# param for specifying number of lines to tail.
#$n =  CGI::param('n');
$n = '20';
$file_name = "/var/log/nginx/access.log";

#show 100 lines by default
$tail = $n?$n:100;

# specifying default as of now
$file_name = $file_name?$file_name:"$file_name";

# tail -n <tail_lines>. Start with tail_lines
$tail_lines=10;

$tail_file=File::Tail->new(name=>$file_name,
                            maxinterval=>2,
                            adjustafter=>1,
                            maxbuf=>16384,
                            tail=>$tail_lines);


while (defined($readline=$tail_file->read))
{
    print $readline."</br>";
}
```

i have given permission to as follows

-rw-r--r--. 1 nginx nginx 32565 Jan  7 17:17 /var/log/nginx/access.log

and i am facing this problem with tailf only..............

permission related in nginx log

```
[Tue Jan 07 17:16:07 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Error opening /var/log/nginx/access.log: Permission denied at /var/www/cgi-bin/clarity.pl line 32, referer: http://host:8888/clarity.html
```

help me out from this problem...?

Comment: Depending on what `grep` is on your system, using `-r` as you are doing will cause a bit of nuttiness as it recursively greps through the httpd working directory. I don't mean to sound harsh, but your script is a bit terrifying. You may want to Google "perl sanitize CGI input", as well as looking into why you really never want to pass anything through to the shell. Consider opening and reading the logs within your Perl script, rather than shelling out to cat/grep, and use a sanitized `\Q$test\E` matching expression to do your grepping.  God speed!

Comment: @codnodder but i am facing problem with tail only.

Comment: That is simply a permissions issue. If you check the permissions of the folders up from your log file you will find one that is not readable by the web server process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set something up such that the perl CGI script runs as a separate user?

Typically most modern nginx installations have scripts executing as a different user. This way if someone hacks into your CGI script, they cannot easily affect the actual web server process.

You can try something like

```
print "real uid: $<, effective uid: $>\n";
```

in a separate CGI script to test what user your script is actually running as.